# basic authentication(inmemory) for java web application which is run on tomcat like apache basic authentication

Tags: spring, apache, basic-authentication, tomcat8

I have java web application which is run on tomcat 8 in test environment and it is included login/logout(spring-security) feature but I don't want it to use without knowing basic authentication username/password(event login page).
So, how can I configure basic authentication(inmemory) for java web application like apache basic authentication in linux?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes I have tried  Realm(in memory) in tomcat but tomcat use db connection of my application. Reference: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/realm-howto.html#MemoryRealm , http://www.techpaste.com/2013/11/protect-access-resource-memory-realm-tomcat/

Comment: I mean can you show what you have tried within your application? Or am I misreading your question?

Comment: If you already use Spring Security why even trying to configure basic auth in tomcat? Just enable it in Spring Security.